# Passing classes to worker in QThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm developing an application which parses a list of binary files and saves the results into a database. The processing of the files takes a rather long time. Therefore I'm showing the user a progress bar and a list of processed files. When a file is successfully processed, I want to update the processbar. If the user aborts the processing (i.e. clicks on the window's 'x' -> &ParseAssistant::rejected), I need to kill the thread and delete the allocated objects (i.e. PluginWorker* and QThread*).

```
/* mainwindow.cpp */

ParseAssistant parseWindow(files.size());

QThread* thread = new QThread();
PluginWorker* worker = new PluginWorker(pluginConnector, pluginProcessor, files);
worker->moveToThread(thread);

// Update GUI (progressbar + filelist)
connect(worker, &PluginWorker::updateProgress, &parseWindow, &ParseAssistant::updateProgress);

connect(thread, SIGNAL (started()), worker, SLOT (process()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL (finished()), thread, SLOT (quit()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL (finished()), thread, SLOT (deleteLater()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL (finished()), worker, SLOT (deleteLater()));

// Stop PluginWorker on 'x'-click
connect(&parseWindow, &ParseAssistant::rejected, worker, &PluginWorker::stop);
connect(worker, &PluginWorker::finished, &parseWindow, &ParseAssistant::parsingFinished);

thread->start();

parseWindow.exec();
```

First, I'm creating a QDialog (ParseAssistant) which contains the progressbar and the list of processed files. Afterwards I create a Worker-Thread-pair and bind them as described in ['How To Really, Truly Use QThreads'](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/). The 'pluginConnector' has access to the plugin an parses the files; the pluginProcessor writes the results to a database.

```
/* pluginworker.cpp */

PluginWorker::PluginWorker(PluginConnector& pc, PluginProcessor& processor, QStringList list)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(parseNext(int)), this, SLOT(process(int)));
}

// Called on 'x'-press
void PluginWorker::stop()
{
    isStopped = true;
}

void PluginWorker::process(int idx)
{
    if (isStopped) {
        emit finished();
        return;
    }

    if (0 <= idx && idx < files.length()) {
        /* 
         *  Parse file using PluginConnector and 
         *  use result with PluginProcessor
         */

        emit updateProgress(idx+1, error, source);
        emit parseNext(idx+1);
    } else {
        emit finished();
    }
}
```

I use signals/slots to call parseNext, because this allows Qt to call stop() (when &ParseAssistant::rejected signal is received). An alternative would be to iterate over the files and call QCoreApplication::processEvents to process signals.

This construct mostly works, but crashes when I abort the process using the 'x'. I can't track down exactly what crashes the application, but I'm fairly certain that my approach is flawed, because the 'worker' and the 'pluginConnector/pluginProcessor' live in different threads, but I don't know how to correctly use this.

Comment: http://blog.debao.me/2013/08/how-to-use-qthread-in-the-right-way-part-1/

Comment: This is pretty much what the QtConcurrent module is for. Then you don't even need to be aware that `QThread` exists, the implementation details such as this are handled for you.

Comment: @Deep I don't know how to apply the blog-post here, because I'm already using a variation of "Usage 2-0"

Comment: @KubaOber Could you elaborate on the QtConcurrent approach? Unfortunately, the PluginConnector uses dynamic memory allocation (i.e. it returns ProcessResult*). This implies two things: 1) The allocation and cleanup need to happen in the same thread i.e. I can not return the results of something like "QtConcurrent::mapped()" (as far as I can tell) and 2) The stopping needs to be gracefully (i.e. the thread mustn't be stopped if memory has been allocated but not been freed).

Comment: int exitCode = qtApp.exec(); /* something more */ thread.quit(); thread.wait(); return exitCode; // main

Comment: @Deep Thanks, this works without crashing. But I'm not quite sure why / how. Could you explain why "pluginConnector" and "pluginProcessor" can be called from the Worker-Object although they were created in the main thread?

"creating an object in one thread and calling its functions from another thread is not guaranteed to work" http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html

Do I need additonal moveToThread() calls?

Comment: moveToThread() need call only once after new worker creation. After moving worker to other thread it live inside thread and can be call directly without problem (of course from this thread). And U can call from other thread but be careful with "shared" data, here can be UB and/or race condition - if U need, for fix it use mutex. Not need additional calls to moveToThread(). But for correct thread quit U must call thread.wait()

Comment: I understand that the worker is living in the new thread; but the worker is using functions from objects (namely pluginConnector and pluginProcessor), which still live in the main-thread. From my understanding the worker should _not_ be able to call the objects' functions (they live in different threads after all). Why is the worker nevertheless able to call them?

Comment: Objects are in memory for your application. You have access and can call them. But You must be careful.

Comment: Ah okay, I thought threads could not access each other's stacks. If you want, you may answer the question so I can accept it.